# polymer dom-repeat failing to update after array update

Tags: arrays, polymer, repeat, mutation

I have a polymer property like the below.

gamma:{type:Array,observe:true,notify:true,value: [{"id":1,"value":["w"]},
                                {"id":2,"value":["w"]}]}

And i am using this property to display rows and columns in template using divs.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{gamma}}" id="maindiv">
            <div class="layout__row">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.value}}">
                <div class="layout__block" id$="{{item}}">
                    <button class="btn btn--primary margins">Add {{item}}      Button</button>
                </div>
            </template>
            </div>
            </template>
```

And if i modify the gamma property to add one more value in first object, and call notifysplices, its not rendering the divs according to the number. i am calling render function  from the add columns method.

i have another method called addrows, which has this code.

```
addRows: function(){
                    this.push("gamma", {"id":this.rows.length+1,"value":     ["w"]} );
                    this.$.maindiv.render();
                    this.$.rowdiv.render();
                }
```

what i am missing here.

**i found the solution, the sub-property or nested array change should be like the below.**

this.push(["gamma", i, "value"], "a");

credit goes to Arthur Evans from polymer.slack.com

Comment: in docs 'data binding/binding to structured data' is  little note on 'set api' .... if you are not getting the type of observed and listener response that you expect, u may try using the set api when you change valueOf(gamma)

Comment: i tried setting the set too, this is how i used, correct me if my syntax is wrong. this.set('gamma.i.value', this.gamma[i].value);

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your definition of the `gamma` property is causing the problem. According to the polymer docs

> If the default value should be an array or object unique to the instance, create the array or object inside a function. See [Configuring default property values](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#configure-values) for more information.

So your definition should be:

```
gamma: {
    type: Array,
    observe: true,
    notify: true,
    value: function () {
        return [{"id": 1, "value": ["w"]}, {"id": 2, "value": ["w"]}]
    }
}
```